# Criar uma conexão com banco de dados mysql com php usando new PDO em uma classe e chamar outra

Tags: php, mysql

Bem, eu queria fazer uma conexão com bando de dados mysql porém sem precisar ficar colocando

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=database', 'user', '');
```

Em toda nova classe que eu criar, sendo assim existe uma maneira de criar uma classe só para a conexão e chamar ela em outras usando require?

Comment: bando de dados?

Comment: Veja se este exemplo atende a sua necessidade https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43630810/how-to-use-pdo-connection-in-other-classes

Comment: Não precisa criar nada, `new PDO` já retorna uma instância de classe. É só por essa linha num arquivo e usar require_once, ou configurar num [auto prepend](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) se for usar em todas as páginas. No caso até é melhor usar a lib nativa mysqli, mais eficiente. Não saia criando classe a toa em PHP (é até absurdo para algo que usa uma instância só), isso é vício de "blogueiro" e cursinhos duvidosos, não de programador experiente. Para aprendizado é fundamental se basear na minoria que usa certo, não a maioria que propaga desinformação.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Primeiro você cria um arquivo com essa classe:

```
 <?php
     Class Conexao{
     private $host= "127.0.0.1";
     private $dbname= "database";
     private $user = "user";
     private $pass = "";
     private $dbh;
    
     function conectar(){
       $this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbname;$this->user;$this->pass");
       return $this->dbh;
     }
    }
?>
```

Sempre que você precisa utilizar o codigo é usar vc chamar o arquivo, por exemplo:

```
<?php
 include "arquivo.php";
 $objeto = new Conexao;
 $conn = $objeto->conectar();
 
 // exemplo utilizando a consulta
 $query= $conn->prepare("Select * from tabela");
 $query->execute();
?>
```